# Sails js and GeoJSON format

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, leaflet, sails.js

anybody knows how to store GEOJSON in sails js models? 
i want to store features and points in sails js models.

```
var geojsonFeature = {
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
    "name": "Coors Field",
    "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
    "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
},
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
}
```

};

Answer (score 1):

In [Sails' Attributes documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes) you can find that there are 5 types supported by Sail's Waterline (the underlying ORM within Sails)

- string
- number
- boolean
- json
- ref

In your case, you have several objects embedded. Something like the following would probably work:

```js
attributes: {
  type: {
    type: 'string',
    enum: ['Feature','This','That','Other'], // not required...
  },
  properties: {
    type: 'json'
  },
  geometry: {
    type: 'json'
  }
}
```